# Where is the midpoint of random-float 1?

Tags: random, netlogo

Netlogo dictionary says: 
"If number is positive, reports a random floating point number greater than or equal to 0 but strictly less than number."

```
random-float 1
```

will generate a number greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1. To evenly split the results, is the proper split

```
if x < 0.5
```

or

```
if x <= 0.5
```

My guess is that the distance from 0 to just before 0.5 is equal to the distance from 5 to just before 1.0,  so that  x < 0.5 is the correct answer.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. This is covered in the NetLogo FAQ, here: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#onepointoh

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it to see how many decimel places the normal random-float 1 goes to and i got :

```
show random-float 1
0.24664519166881826
```

the odds of actually landing on a 0.50000000000000000 vs. 0.50000000000000001  is incredibly low and I would not worry about using 0.5<= or 0.5>=. If you *reaaally* want to have it be even, you could use

```
set blah .5
while [blah = .5] [    
set blah random-float 1 ]
```

to make it re-roll a number if it truely lands on 0.5. Or you can *one-of* to select one of 2 possible outcomes.

Perhaps a developer will pipe in with more explicit technical advice.

Comment: Yes, it was really a technical question, not a practical questions.